# How to add selectable to data return from jquery .post()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a jquery-ui selectable to data that is returned from a jquery .post(). It seems as though the selector for that is created in the data from the post is not being recognized.  I am thinking that I can use .live() but i'm not sure.

This is the code that I am using:

```
$.post('middleman.php', { request:"getfeedbacknav"}, function(data) {
       $('#feedbacknav').html(data);
});
$( "#selectable" ).selectable();
```

Here is the data that I am trying to make selectable:

```
<div id="feedbacknav" width="20%">
<h3>Feedback</h3>
<br>
<ol id="selectable" width="100%">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
        <div width="8%"><img src="image/faces/sad_face_3.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        </div>
        <div width="88%" style="padding-top:8px;" id="fb_5678908'">
            intial feedback
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
        <div width="8%"><img src="image/faces/happy_face_3.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        </div>
        <div width="88%" style="padding-top:8px;" id="fb_1328896423'">
            Server : Bryan
            Comments : Ok
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">
        <div width="8%"><img src="image/faces/happy_face_2.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        </div>
        <div width="88%" style="padding-top:8px;" id="fb_1328898803'">
            Server : Russ
            Comments : He was nice
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The `ol` is showing up when I inspect in chrome but it is not showing up when I view the page source. I am not getting any errors either.

Comment: View Source only shows HTML that was initially sent when the page was loaded, it doesn't reflect changes to the DOM as a result of Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call .selectable after the HTML from the server is returned and is rendered in the browser. the way you have it now, it would be called immediately after the Post and the result of the Post is not yet available and so $( "#selectable" ) is empty.

```
$.post('middleman.php', { request:"getfeedbacknav"}, function(data) {
    $('#feedbacknav').html(data);
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the selectable in the callback of the $.post method, otherwise it runs before the content is actually added to the DOM:

```
$.post('middleman.php', { request:"getfeedbacknav"}, function(data) {
       $('#feedbacknav').html(data);
       $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The newly created `ol` is not showing in page source because JavaScript
   adds them dynamically and ViewSource shows only the static
   elements. JavaScript does not physically write the new elements to
   the static source rather add them to DOM (Document Object Model). It
   creates them on the client-side or can say virtually.
2. You can use `live()` or event delegation methods as well. This [page](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/09/working-with-events-part-3-more-event-delegation-with-jquery) has nice tutorial for it.